# How to create this bouncing square in flutter using the flutter code?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image: How to create this bouncing square in flutter using the flutter code? This is I want to make using the listView.]
How to create this bouncing square in flutter using the flutter code? This is I want to make using the listView